# Is there a good source that gives an overview of linq optimizations?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Linq does a lot of clever things such as returning the result of the Count-property using the `Count`() method on a `IList`.
Is there a good source that gives an overview of this optimizations?

It would be very interesting because as before I knew the above, I never used `Count()` and thus often returned a `List<T>` than only an `IEnumerable<T>` because i knew that the caller will need need often the instance-count of the list.

But having in mind that Count() does not really count the instances contained in the `IEnumerable<T>` but returns the result of the Count-property from the returned List and therefore not loosing performance occasioned me to change a lot of my returning types from a List to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: what does "Linq does a lot of optimizations such as returning the result of the Count-property using the Count() method on a IList" mean???

Comment: @Mitch: Presumably that a LINQ query does not retrieve all of the underlying data when a simple `Count()` call will do.

Comment: I learned a few minutes ago that calling AsEnumerable on a list does not create a new instance but only return the instance itself. But maybe the word optimization is not the right. A have changed the question-text to show more exactly what I mean.

Comment: Don't agree with you, these are heuristics, it has everything to do with optimization.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the "linq cleverness" to a question? e.g. "[Is there a good source that gives an] overview of linq optimizations?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current optimisations that I'm aware of:

- [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) uses the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3kzhec.aspx) property if the sequence implements [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) and a predicate isn't used. (In .NET 4 `Count` is also optimised for the non-generic [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx).)
- [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx)/[`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) access by index if the sequence implements [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx).
- [`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx)/[`LastOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx) access by index if the sequence implements `IList<T>` and a predicate isn't used.
- [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx)/[`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)  use the `Count` property to allocate memory more efficiently if the sequence implements `ICollection<T>`. (But neither of them optimise for `ICollection`.)

Optimisations that could be there but aren't:

- `Last`/`LastOrDefault` don't optimise in the case where a predicate is used. There's no reason why they couldn't optimise for `IList<T>`, iterating backwards through the list and accessing each element by index.
- [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx) could optimise for `ICollection<T>` and `ICollection`, using the `Count` property to determine if the lists are the same length and breaking out early if they're not.
- [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) could optimise for `IList<T>`, accessing the elements by index and starting directly at index *n* rather than iterating and discarding the first *n* elements.
- `ToArray`/`ToList` could also optimise for `ICollection`, using the `Count` property to allocate memory more efficiently.
- [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) could optimise for `ICollection<T>` and `ICollection`, using the `Count` property to allocate memory more efficently.

Comment: I've researched this in depth using Reflector while developing the [Nito.Linq](http://nitolinq.codeplex.com/) library. Luke's answer is pretty complete. I would only add that `ToList` and `ToArray` do use `Count` to reduce memory reallocations. Also, `Empty` and `SequenceEqual` could be potentially optimized by using `Count`. Finally, there's also a potential for optimizing `Reverse`, but it's controversial because it changes the semantics [from buffering to streaming](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you.aspx).

Comment: @Stephen: I forgot all about the possible optimisation of `SequenceEqual`, even though I have an optimised version in my own LINQ helper library. I'll add it to the list. Could you elaborate on how `Empty` might be optimised? As far as I'm aware, it just returns a singleton empty sequence.

Comment: You're correct; I double-checked my notes and `Empty` was put in my comment by mistake. Sorry...

Answer (score 13):

Try the [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). It's a great tool for browsing class libraries, it has a powerful decompiler which let's you view the source code pretty much as it was written.

e.g. The `Count()` extension method is implemented like this

```
if (source == null)
{
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
}
ICollection<TSource> is2 = source as ICollection<TSource>;
if (is2 != null)
{
    return is2.Count;
}
ICollection is3 = source as ICollection;
if (is3 != null)
{
    return is3.Count;
}
int num = 0;
using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        num++;
    }
}
return num;
```

At the off chance that the source does not implement the collection interface you'll have to count to get the actual acount. Browsing the code this way is a great way to learn.